# No points displayed in a graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, signal-processing

i was looking for a way to display the points in this graph

Comment: Can you share the file `route1`?

Answer (score 0):

To find turning points, you actually want the angle of two vectors be **small**, because **small** theta is associated with greatest change in direction.

Just change `idx = np.where(theta > min_angle)[0]+1` to 
`idx = np.where(theta < np.pi)[0] + 1`.

Here's what I got:

[image]